# Filter query through an ID to another table in Django

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have this query

**Table 1**

```
cardId = 1
table_1 = card_tbl.ocabjects.get(id=cardId).values('category1_id')
```

and the **Output** for this is Table 1 is `<QuerySet [{'category1_id': 1}]>`

Next is I want to match the value of `table 1` to `table 2`

**Table 2** but it returns an error

```
table_2 = category1_tbl.objects.filter(Q(id=table_1))
print(table_2.name)
```

The `table 2` contains column which is a `name` and I want just to get result name through matching ID from different `table` for example name `jason` The table_2 have a column name

Need help

Comment: alteast create a foriegn key relationship.Other wise how can you match both table is there is any unique id common to both?.

Answer (score 0):

I cant get your exact point but if you want to filter from table 2 according to the ids of table 1.

**can do this**

```
 table_2 = category1_tbl.objects.filter(id=table_1.category1_id))
    print(table_2.first().name)
```

Comment: thanks for your response I edited my question and I just want to return one value through printing it, need help

Comment: I think you want this:
table_2 = category1_tbl.objects.filter(id=table_1.category1_id))
print(table_2.first().name) <- it return first()